# Access field content and display in template by URL

Tags: python, django

I have a model in Django:

```
class Items(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In the database there are 3 items: id=1 Item1, id=2 Item2, id=3 Item3
I would like to display these items in my template index.html when I access their id in the URL

Ex: HTTP:/server-name/1 display Item1
    http:/server-name/2 display Item2
    http:/server-name/3 display Item3

Comment: Since this is the fundamental thing that Django does, and is fully covered in the tutorial, what is your question?

Comment: I'm new in django. So I have 3 items registered in the database. I would like to display these items in my template by accessin the id of these items in the url. For example : http:/server-name/1  can display Item1 (where 1 is the id of Item1)

Answer (score 0):

In your view, define:

```
def your_view(request):

queryset = Items.objects.all()

context = {
    "object_list": queryset,
}

return render(request,'list_templ.html',context)
```

In your template:

```
{%  for obj in object_list %}

{{ obj.item  }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh, and by the way, you might want to take a look the YouTube Channel by CodingEntrepreneurs. The have a good tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, it works. It displays the 3 items in a line. However, what I need is accessing one item just adding its id in the end of the page URL. So that  
http://servername/index/1   will show the page index and the Item1 in this page

Comment: Okay.. You really should watch the tutorian by Coding for entrepreneurs. They explain everything really good.